# Bootsfaces specific row color (bug?)

Tags: css, jsf, mojarra, bootsfaces

```
Using Java JDK 8, Mojjara 2.2.9 and Bootsfaces 1.1.3.
```

Hello. I am creating a simple data table using bootsfaces in a simple java project:

```
<b:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}" var="foo" styleClass="colored">
    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{foo.ID} order="asc"/>
    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{foo.foo}"/>
    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{foo.bar}"/>
</b:dataTable>
```

Everything works well until now.

My requirement is to **highlight the first generated row of this table** (not the header).

An elegant approach I tried was by using CSS selector **nth-child(x)**.

It rendered the color but for the desired row. For instance:

By using:

```
.colored tr:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #f7ca18;
}
```

The result was highlighting the 2nd row of the data table (excepting the header):
[image]

And for:

```
 .colored tr:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #f7ca18;
}
```

It colored the header (which is worse):
[image]

It is weird what is happening. The first row of the data table is ignored in both situations. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or it is something wrong with this `<b:dataTable>` .. Thank you

Comment: What about `.colored tbody tr:nth-child(1)` or something similar? What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: I forgot to add that command also. By using `.colored tbody tr:nth-child(1)`  it does not render any color at all. The table rows remain white...

Comment: I noticed now that the table already has some stripped lines and I searched in bootsfaces documentation to disable them. Now the first row is highlighted as expected....this issue drove me crazy..